# Equivalent/Alternative of HTML <abbr> tag in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android

If I put the `<abbr>` tag in an HTML webpage like so in the snippet below, there will be a text `WHO`, which upon hovering will show its full form `World Health Organization` in a small box beside it.

```html
<abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr>
```

How to replicate the same thing in Android? (I am using Java btw) You may not be able to hover on a mobile device, but can this functionality be replicated on click? If so, how?

For example, I have a paragraph in a `TextView` like so

```
HTML is not a programming lang...
```

I want it so that when the user clicks on the specific word "HTML" its full form should show beside it (In some sort of "floating" box)

Maybe make a small box, position it accordingly and then toggle its visibility on click? I don't know where to start.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Android is an operating system. What do you want to do? Write an app that displays HTML text?

Comment: @GhostCat No, I want to create an Android app which has text, some words in it which are written in short form, when you click on those words a small box appears beside them showing the full form of that word, like it gets shown in the snippet above

Comment: https://modernweb.com/enhancing-the-html-abbr-element-on-mobile/

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks for your response, but that solution would work only if I was using something like a WebView to display HTML/CSS content, right? It would be very inconvenient to add a WebView in a paragraph each time I want abbreviated text, is there any other way or I am misunderstanding your response?

Comment: The solution is old (2013), and I cannot remember it anymore, but it seems to be pure CSS. I hope I did not burden you with additional garbage.

Comment: Any screen element can be made clickable, and the click actions are arbitrary. Without knowing anything about your app, how text us being displayed, etc it’s impossible to guess what might work for you.